# JSSOR Out Captions wont trigger

Tags: javascript, html, jssor

I am using the following code to display a JSSOR slider.

The slider itself works fine, as do the PlayIn captions, but I cant get the PlayOut transitions to work.

I am trying to achieve something similar to this site, so that the caption exits before the slide changes.

http://goo.gl/7dAXt

Here is my Script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jssor.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jssor.utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jssor.slider.js"></script>
<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        var _CaptionTransitions = [];

        _CaptionTransitions["transition_name1"] = {$Duration:900,$FlyDirection:1,$Easing:{$Left:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine},$ScaleHorizontal:0.6,$Opacity:2};
        _CaptionTransitions["transition_name2"] = {$Duration:1500,$Rotate:-1,$FlyDirection:5,$Easing:$JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear,$ScaleHorizontal:0.5,$ScaleVertical:0.5,$Opacity:2,$During:{$Left:[0,0.33],$Top:[0.67,0.33],$Rotate:[0,0.33]},$Round:{$Rotate:0.25}};            

            var options = {
            $AutoPlay: false,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
            $AutoPlaySteps: 1,                                  //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), the default value is 1
            $AutoPlayInterval: 2000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
            $PauseOnHover: 0,                               //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, default value is 1

            $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
            $SlideDuration: 300,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
            $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 80,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
            //$SlideWidth: 600,                                 //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
            //$SlideHeight: 150,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
            $SlideSpacing: 3,                                   //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
            $DisplayPieces: 1,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
            $ParkingPosition: 0,                                //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
            $UISearchMode: 0,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
            $PlayOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, default value is 1
            $DragOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0),

            $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,              //[Required] Class to create thumbnail navigator instance
                $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always

                $ActionMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None, 1 act by click, 2 act by mouse hover, 3 both, default value is 1
                $AutoCenter: 0,                                 //[Optional] Auto center thumbnail items in the thumbnail navigator container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 3
                $Lanes: 1,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange thumbnails, default value is 1
                $SpacingX: 0,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
                $SpacingY: 0,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
                $DisplayPieces: 6,                              //[Optional] Number of pieces to display, default value is 1
                $ParkingPosition: 0,                          //[Optional] The offset position to park thumbnail
                $Orientation: 2,                                //[Optional] Orientation to arrange thumbnails, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, default value is 1
                $DisableDrag: false                            //[Optional] Disable drag or not, default value is false
            },

            $CaptionSliderOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorCaptionSlider$,
            $CaptionTransitions: _CaptionTransitions,
            $PlayInMode: 1,
            $PlayOutMode: 3
        },

            };

            var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('slider1_container', options);
```

...and here is my HTML

```
    <!-- Loading Screen -->
    <div u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
        <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity:0.7; position: absolute; display: block;
            background-color: #fff; top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
        </div>
        <div style="position: absolute; display: block; background: url(../img/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
            top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 200px;height:200px;">
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Slides Container -->
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: default; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 960px; height: 385px;
        overflow: hidden;">
                    <!--SLIDE ONE-->
                    <div>
                    <img u="image" src="../images/data-center-servers.jpg" />
                            <div u="caption" t="NO" t2="transition_name2" style="position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 375px; width: 500px;height: 50px;">
                            <h1>Any HTML Content Here</h1>
                            <a href="../virtualisation.html" class="button">Click Here</a>
                            </div>

                    <div u="thumb">
                    <div class="title_back">
                    </div>
                    <div class="title">
                    Virtualisation
                    <img src="../images/virtualisation-icon.png" alt="Virtual Infrastructure" class="virtualicon">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>              

                    <!--SLIDE TWO-->
                    <div>
                    <img u="image" src="../images/clouds.jpg" />
                            <div u="caption" t="transition_name1" style="position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 375px; width: 500px;height: 50px;">
                            <h1>Any HTML Content Here</h1>
                            </div>

                    <div u="thumb">
                    <div class="title_back">
                    </div>
                    <div class="title">
                    Cloud and Hosting
                    <img src="../images/cloud-icon.png" alt="Cloud and Hosting" class="cloudicon">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    <!--SLIDE THREE-->
                    <div>
                    <img u="image" src="../images/collaboration.jpg" />
                            <div u="caption" t="transition_name1" style="position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 375px; width: 500px;height: 50px;">
                            <h1>Any HTML Content Here</h1>
                            </div>

                    <div u="thumb">
                    <div class="title_back">
                    </div>
                    <div class="title">
                    Collaboration
                    <img src="../images/collaboration-icon.png" alt="Collaboration" class="collaborationicon">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>              

                    <!--SLIDE FOUR-->
                    <div>
                    <img u="image" src="../images/fingerprint.jpg" />
                            <div u="caption" t="transition_name1" style="position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 375px; width: 500px;height: 50px;">
                            <h1>Any HTML Content Here</h1>
                            </div>

                    <div u="thumb">
                    <div class="title_back">
                    </div>
                    <div class="title">
                    Cyber Security
                    <img src="../images/security-icon.png" alt="Cyber Security" class="securityicon">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    <!--SLIDE FIVE-->
                    <div>
                    <img u="image" src="../images/fire.jpg" />
                            <div u="caption" t="transition_name1" style="position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 375px; width: 500px;height: 50px;">
                            <h1>Any HTML Content Here</h1>
                            </div>

                    <div u="thumb">
                    <div class="title_back">
                    </div>
                    <div class="title">
                    Disaster Recovery
                    <img src="../images/dr-icon.png" alt="Disaster Recovery" class="dricon">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>              

                    <!--SLIDE SIX-->
                    <div>
                    <img u="image" src="../images/network.jpg" />
                            <div u="caption" t="transition_name1" style="position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 375px; width: 500px;height: 50px;">
                            <h1>Any HTML Content Here</h1>
                            </div>

                    <div u="thumb">
                    <div class="title_back">
                    </div>
                    <div class="title">
                    Managed Networks
                    <img src="../images/networking-icon.png" alt="Managed Networks" class="networkingicon">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>

               </div> <!--END of u slides-->

        <!-- Trigger -->
        <script>jssor_slider1('slider1_container');</script>

    <!--Slider Navigation Buttons-->
    <!-- ThumbnailNavigator Skin Begin -->
    <div u="thumbnavigator" class="jssort12" style="cursor: pointer; position: absolute; width: 203px; height: 360px; left:128px; top: 0px;">
        <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin Begin -->
        <div u="slides" style="cursor: pointer;">
            <div u="prototype" class=p style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 203px; HEIGHT: 60px; TOP: 0; LEFT: 0;">
                <thumbnailtemplate style="WIDTH: 203px; HEIGHT: 60px; border: none; position: absolute; TOP: 0; LEFT: 0; "></thumbnailtemplate>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin End -->
    </div> <!-- ThumbnailNavigator Skin End -->

</div> <!--END CONTAINER-->
```

Here is the URL to my development site.

http://goo.gl/WDkWD1

At the moment I can not get exit captions to work at all. I have tried both $PlayOutMode: 3 and 1

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: $PlayOutMode works only when $AutoPlay is true. Caption can play out only when a slider is auto-play.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. That's a shame, can you think of any way I can mimic the function of the IBM slider using JSSOR?

Comment: IBM Slider: http://goo.gl/7dAXt

Comment: Seems there is no workaround at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I think its the last comma after the closing bracket for

```
     $CaptionSliderOptions: { blah blah $PlayOutMode: 3},  see that comma to the left there.
```

i reckon remove that because i think the code is looking for another argument like Arrow Options or Bullet Options. Looking at the source code of their demos clearly shows no comma just before the responsive stuff....should end like the following.

```
    }
      };
     var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('slider1_container', options);
```